# button OnClickListener works only one time android

Tags: android, listener

i have activity below. when i run the app it only works one time and when i press `storeBTN` or `retrieveBTN` after first time i see no changes in `Textview` and no log about running `store()` and `retrieve()` functions.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button storeBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    storeBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            store(i);
        }
    });
    Button retrieveBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    retrieveBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            retrieve();
        }
    });

}
public void store(int newHighScore){
    Log.d("Meeeeee", "store: "+newHighScore);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(this.MODE_APPEND);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
    boolean b = editor.commit();
    Log.d("Meeee", "store: commited? "+b);
    retrieve();
    return;
}
public void retrieve(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(this.MODE_APPEND);
    int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default);
    long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
    Log.d("meeee", "retrieve: "+highScore+" in mode: "+this.MODE_APPEND);
    TextView scoreTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    scoreTV.setText(highScore+"");
    return;
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `store()`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

from store() method

Comment: lol thanks i don't know where that came from i think that's because of CTRL+X for delete line in the Intellij(android studio) -_-

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view the problem was that you add click listner in onCreate() method, i suggest use click listener like below code,

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Kintan Patel on 01-Aug-16.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button storeBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        storeBTN.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button retrieveBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        storeBTN.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.R.id.button1:
            // storeBTN button click
            break;
            case R.id.R.id.button2:
            //retrieveBTN click
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

in this code i add only two line and an one implement one method ,

```
  implements View.OnClickListener
  storeBTN.setOnClickListener(this);
  storeBTN.setOnClickListener(this);
```

after implement method android studio give error to override method ,so simple override click method,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.R.id.button1:
            // storeBTN button click
            break;
            case R.id.R.id.button2:
            //retrieveBTN click
            break;

        }
    }
```

So ,in feature you have more button in single page your code is clean and easy to understand.

If you have any query please feel free to ask.

Comment: This is not the answer of the question. You just suggested him how to write better code.